# Max date of last data entry that falls under where condition

Tags: sql-server

I have this one table, table1

```
cust_id     Date            Value
1           2019-10-01      25
1           2019-10-19      35
1           2018-08-27      29
1           2019-07-09      35
1           2019-10-15      55
2           2019-09-26      45
2           2019-06-19      31
2           2019-07-19      8
```

I wrote a query:

```
select 
 t1.value, 
 max(t1.date) as max_date
 from table1 t1
  where   
   t1.cust_id = '1'
   and (t1.date >= '2019-09-30 and t1.date <= 2019-10-31)
   and t1.value > 25
group by t1.value
```

but it is giving me:

```
cust_id     max_date            Value
1           10/1/2019           25
1           10/19/2019          35
1           10/15/2019          55
```

Would like to just get:

The latest date entry that have the value of over 25.

```
cust_id     max_date          Value
1           10/19/2019        35
```

Comment: Are you storing strings instead of dates? Don't, that's a serious bug. Use the proper type, in this case `date`. There's no way to perform a range search with strings in this format - `10/19/2019` will always come *after* `09/19/1800`. You could cover up the problem by parsing the strings, but the server won't be able to use any indexes covering the Date field

Comment: That is because you don't have your date literals correct. When you say 09/30/2019 it calculates that as math first which results in 0. Then the 0 is implicitly converted to a datetime and every value in your table is greater than January 1st 1900. You should use ANSI compliant date literals like 'YYYYMMDD', notice the single quotes. Yours would be '20190930' and '20191030'. And that is assuming you have the date or datetime datatype in your table.

Comment: I think you have a combination of bad things here. Both storing strings as dates and improperly writing the literals in a query.

Comment: Not to mention, the where clause in posted query isn't referring to an appropriate table; I'm going to assume this is a typo.   It would throw an error as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This presumes there are no duplicate dates.  You have to select the row where the date = the max date that matches your criteria:

```
select cust_id, value, date as max_date
from table1
where date = (select max(date)
              from table1
              where cust_id = '1'
                 and date >= '2019-09-30'
                 and date <= '2019-10-31'
                 and value > 25
             )
```

Comment: I still see errors in this suggestion (though I see where you're going with it).   I assume OP fixed the changes on their end.  Single quotes around the dates weren't specified correctly, and table alias wasn't set right.

Comment: Thanks -- I fixed those things (had just copied from OP).

Comment: Not a problem.   Just figured it would be appropriate for it to be right, in case someone else comes looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the maximum date for each customer where the value is greater than 25 and join to the whole table to get the other values. Like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7cdc95af9ed872d3107f6a544efeb88)...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #table1;
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
    cust_id INTEGER NOT NULL
  , Date DATE NOT NULL
  , Value INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #table1
(
    cust_id
  , Date
  , Value
)
VALUES
(1, '10/1/2019', 25)
, (1, '10/19/2019', 35)
, (1, '8/27/2019', 29)
, (1, '7/9/2019', 35)
, (1, '10/15/2019', 55)
, (2, '9/26/2019', 45)
, (2, '6/19/2019', 31)
, (2, '7/19/2019', 8);

SELECT     t1.*
FROM       #table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN (
               SELECT   cust_id
                      , MAX(Date) AS max_date
               FROM     #table1
               WHERE    Value > 25
               GROUP BY cust_id
           )       AS x ON t1.cust_id = x.cust_id
                           AND t1.Date = x.max_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your Date column set as a Date rather than Varchar/String, and Cust_ID and Value as Integers, I would do the following:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.Custdate DESC), Cust_id, CustDate, Value 
  FROM table1 t1
  WHERE (t1.Custdate >= '09/30/2019' and t1.Custdate <= '10/30/2019')
  Group by CustDate, Cust_id, Value
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1;
```

This query assumes you're running SQL 2005 or newer.  Here's a SQL Fiddle for reference. I also think this would take care of duplicates too, but needs testing.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7ce8/44