# query max date of all customers that falls under a where condition

Tags: sql-server

I would like to query the max date only of all customers that has a value of 25.

Table1

```
cust_id     Date            Value
1           2019-10-01      25
1           2019-10-19      35
1           2018-08-27      29
1           2019-07-09      35
1           2019-10-15      55
2           2019-09-26      45
2           2019-10-19      31
2           2019-07-19      8
2           2019-10-02      28
3           2019-09-02      36
3           2019-08-15      39
4           2019-10-15      37
4           2019-10-16      36
4           2018-11-18      27
```

wrote this query:

```
select 
 t1.value, 
 max(t1.date) as max_date
 from table1 t1
  where   
   (t1.date >= '2019-09-30 and t1.date <= 2019-10-31)
   and t1.value > 25
group by t1.value
```

but I am getting:

```
cust_id     Date            Value
    1           2019-10-01      25
    1           2019-10-19      35
    1           2019-10-15      55
    2           2019-10-19      31
    2           2019-10-02      28
    4           2019-10-15      37
    4           2019-10-16      36
```

would like to only see the last data entry that is over 25. Something like this:

```
   cust_id     Date            Value
    1           2019-10-19      35
    2           2019-10-19      31
    4           2018-11-16      36
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the same thing as your last question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508866/max-date-of-last-data-entry-that-falls-under-where-condition Just add another where predicate to the wuery you chose as the solution. AND Value > 25

Comment: Yes, I asked the wrong question on that one since I was trying to just limit what I wanted shown but this is covers more of what I really needed. Also the table I posted is just a sample but that table have at least 15000 entries.

Comment: But the answer is still to simply add one more predicate. **AND Value > 25**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max date of last data entry that falls under where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508866/max-date-of-last-data-entry-that-falls-under-where-condition)